# model.detect is not a function at HTMLVideoElement.predictWebcam JS errro

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

Im attempting to build a website that uses a Tensorflow custom model, that uses a webcam for real time object detection. I have the model and the webcam will load in my webpage but I get this error in my console:

```
letsscan1.js:69 Uncaught TypeError: model.detect is not a function
    at HTMLVideoElement.predictWebcam (letsscan1.js:69)
predictWebcam @ letsscan1.js:69
```

model.detect is a function and is called in the HTMLvideoElemenet so I cant understand why Im getting this error.

this is the JS file -

```
//import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
//import { loadGraphModel } from '@tensorflow/tfjs-converter';

const demosSection = document.getElementById('demos');

let MODEL_FILE_URL = 'models/Graph/model.json'; // <-- this variable gets assigned another value below. Changed it to let

// For Keras use tf.loadLayersModel().
const model = tf.loadGraphModel(MODEL_FILE_URL);

// Before we can use COCO-SSD class we must wait for it to finish
// loading. Machine Learning models can be large and take a moment to
// get everything needed to run.
model.then(function(loadedModel) {
    MODEL_FILE_URL = loadedModel; // <-- you were reassigning a value to a const variable here.
    // Show demo section now model is ready to use.
    demosSection.classList.remove('invisible');
});

const video = document.getElementById('webcam');
const liveView = document.getElementById('liveView');

// Check if webcam access is supported.
function hasGetUserMedia() {
    return !!(navigator.mediaDevices &&
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia);
}

// Keep a reference of all the child elements we create
// so we can remove them easilly on each render.
var children = [];


// If webcam supported, add event listener to button for when user
// wants to activate it.
if (hasGetUserMedia()) {
    const enableWebcamButton = document.getElementById('webcamButton');
    enableWebcamButton.addEventListener('click', enableCam);
} else {
    console.warn('getUserMedia() is not supported by your browser');
}


// Enable the live webcam view and start classification.
function enableCam(event) {
    if (!model) {
        console.log('Wait! Model not loaded yet.')
        return;
    }

    // Hide the button.
    event.target.classList.add('removed');

    // getUsermedia parameters.
    const constraints = {
        video: true
    };

    // Activate the webcam stream.
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(stream) {
        video.srcObject = stream;
        video.addEventListener('loadeddata', predictWebcam);
    });
}


function predictWebcam() {
    // Now let's start classifying the stream.
    model.detect(video).then(function(predictions) {
        // Remove any highlighting we did previous frame.
        for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            liveView.removeChild(children[i]);
        }
        children.splice(0);

        // Now lets loop through predictions and draw them to the live view if
        // they have a high confidence score.
        for (let n = 0; n < predictions.length; n++) {
            // If we are over 66% sure we are sure we classified it right, draw it!
            if (predictions[n].score > 0.66) {
                const p = document.createElement('p');
                p.innerText = predictions[n].class + ' - with ' +
                    Math.round(parseFloat(predictions[n].score) * 100) +
                    '% confidence.';
                // Draw in top left of bounding box outline.
                p.style = 'left: ' + predictions[n].bbox[0] + 'px;' +
                    'top: ' + predictions[n].bbox[1] + 'px;' +
                    'width: ' + (predictions[n].bbox[2] - 10) + 'px;';

                // Draw the actual bounding box.
                const highlighter = document.createElement('div');
                highlighter.setAttribute('class', 'highlighter');
                highlighter.style = 'left: ' + predictions[n].bbox[0] + 'px; top: ' +
                    predictions[n].bbox[1] + 'px; width: ' +
                    predictions[n].bbox[2] + 'px; height: ' +
                    predictions[n].bbox[3] + 'px;';

                liveView.appendChild(highlighter);
                liveView.appendChild(p);

                // Store drawn objects in memory so we can delete them next time around.
                children.push(highlighter);
                children.push(p);
            }
        }

        // Call this function again to keep predicting when the browser is ready.
        window.requestAnimationFrame(predictWebcam);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `model.detect(video)` with `model.predict(video)`.

Edit:

As it is a custom model you should load it in like so:

```
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(MODEL_FILE_URL);
```

Comment: that still gives me - ```Uncaught TypeError: model.predict is not a function
    at HTMLVideoElement.predictWebcam```

Comment: that gives me this ```letsscan1.js:9 Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try it this way. You first want to load the model, then save a reference to it, then set your event listeners, then handle the events only when you have your model loaded.

First load the tf script in your html like this (in the head of the html)

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs/dist/tf.min.js"> </script>
```

Then use your js script

```
const demosSection = document.getElementById('demos');

const MODEL_FILE_URL = 'models/Graph/model.json';

// Keep a reference of all the child elements we create
// so we can remove them easilly on each render.
const children = [];
const video = document.getElementById('webcam');
const liveView = document.getElementById('liveView');
const model = null;

// Before we can use COCO-SSD class we must wait for it to finish
// loading. Machine Learning models can be large and take a moment to
// get everything needed to run.
tf.loadGraphModel(MODEL_FILE_URL).then(function(loadedModel) {
    model = loadedModel; // <-- why this line though?

    // If webcam supported, add event listener to button for when user
    // wants to activate it.
    if (hasGetUserMedia()) {
        const enableWebcamButton = document.getElementById('webcamButton');
        enableWebcamButton.addEventListener('click', enableCam);
    } else {
        console.warn('getUserMedia() is not supported by your browser');
    }
    
    demosSection.classList.remove('invisible');
});

// Check if webcam access is supported.
function hasGetUserMedia() {
    return !!(navigator.mediaDevices &&
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia);
}

// Enable the live webcam view and start classification.
function enableCam(event) {
    if (!model) {
        console.log('Wait! Model not loaded yet.')
        return;
    }

    // Hide the button.
    event.target.classList.add('removed');

    // getUsermedia parameters.
    const constraints = {
        video: true
    };

    // Activate the webcam stream.
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(stream) {
        video.srcObject = stream;
        video.addEventListener('loadeddata', predictWebcam);
    });
}


function predictWebcam() {
    // Now let's start classifying the stream.
    model.detect(video).then(function(predictions) {
        // Remove any highlighting we did previous frame.
        for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            liveView.removeChild(children[i]);
        }
        children.splice(0);

        // Now lets loop through predictions and draw them to the live view if
        // they have a high confidence score.
        for (let n = 0; n < predictions.length; n++) {
            // If we are over 66% sure we are sure we classified it right, draw it!
            if (predictions[n].score > 0.66) {
                const p = document.createElement('p');
                p.innerText = predictions[n].class + ' - with ' +
                    Math.round(parseFloat(predictions[n].score) * 100) +
                    '% confidence.';
                // Draw in top left of bounding box outline.
                p.style = 'left: ' + predictions[n].bbox[0] + 'px;' +
                    'top: ' + predictions[n].bbox[1] + 'px;' +
                    'width: ' + (predictions[n].bbox[2] - 10) + 'px;';

                // Draw the actual bounding box.
                const highlighter = document.createElement('div');
                highlighter.setAttribute('class', 'highlighter');
                highlighter.style = 'left: ' + predictions[n].bbox[0] + 'px; top: ' +
                    predictions[n].bbox[1] + 'px; width: ' +
                    predictions[n].bbox[2] + 'px; height: ' +
                    predictions[n].bbox[3] + 'px;';

                liveView.appendChild(highlighter);
                liveView.appendChild(p);

                // Store drawn objects in memory so we can delete them next time around.
                children.push(highlighter);
                children.push(p);
            }
        }

        // Call this function again to keep predicting when the browser is ready.
        window.requestAnimationFrame(predictWebcam);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi that Gives me this error? Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: I changed the code to use only es5. Try it now

Comment: that gave me ```Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at letsscan1.js:1```

Comment: oh yeah, of course, this is running in the browser. removed the first line. if it says tf is not defined, you have to link it in your html

Comment: That has now given me this error ```letsscan1.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
    at letsscan1.js:16```

Comment: You added a comment about the ``` model = loadedModel;``` it was from a code tutorial that used the coco-ssd tensoflow model and I assumed it was important

Comment: just pm me in discord cause this is taking too long